# html5 - Separating header and hX tags

Tags: html, header

I am writing HTML(5) which, on a few different pages, has a number of sections which contain a header (represented by a grey bar). This is a common pattern except for 1 page where this grey bar contains some navigational aids, but the header (as in the h1) is not in the grey bar but beneath it.

In terms of writing semantic HTML5 is it a violation to have something like:

```
<header><a>Go Back<a/></header>

<h1>This is the header</h1>
```

Or should it be:

```
<div class="nav-links"><a>Go Back</a></div>

<header><h1>This is the header</h1></header>
```

The latter requires much more CSS to handle the edge case so if the former is not a violation of HTML then I prefer it.

Does the first way violate HTML5 semantics?

Answer (score 1):

It is valid. You can use [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) for these things.

using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<header><a>Go Back</a>
</header>
<h1>This is the header</h1>
</body></html>
```

Validates so it means it's valid by W3C standards.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask the right question. It is valid html, but does it violate HTML5 semantics?

Comment: They are different ways of evaluating your HTML. For example you can use tables for layout which is valid HTML and will pass the validator, however it violates the semantics of a table, which should only be used for tabulated data.

Comment: What you are saying with <header><h1> is here a header and inside you have a primery header for this elment. I think it is more sementcly correct out side of header element since it hints it is the primery header of the whole document. As you long as its the only h1 in that root element